# Mac OS X El Capitan memory management problems? Apps "not responding"

Tags: macos, memory, performance

I have a MacBook Pro with 16 GB RAM. Current uptime is just 8 days. I may have triggered page out event while also being low on free HDD space.

Now some of the apps won't work despite low memory pressure. When I kill and re-launch some of them, they work well. I've already restarted Chrome, Terminal and some others. I've kept OmniGraffle and some more in hope of really debugging the problem.

[image]

As you can see, the process "OmniGraffle" has most of its memory compressed, and is in "not responding" state. I've put OmniGraffle to foreground and waited for several hours, with no result. The menubar and windows just won't appear. (side note: not a menubar problem. In the other apps, the menubar works fine; I've already killed Dock, Finder, SystemUIServer). The state of process is "S":

```
sh-3.2# ps auwx | grep OmniGraf
pikula         10552   0.0  0.3  3939500  53512   ??  S    Fri08AM   8:12.33 /Applications/OmniGraffle Professional 5.app/Contents/MacOS/OmniGraffle Professional
```

Dtruss won't reveal anything interesting, too:

```
sh-3.2# dtruss -a -p 389
PID/THRD  RELATIVE  ELAPSD    CPU SYSCALL(args)          = return
^C
```

As you can see kernel_task has almost 4 GB RAM. Besides standard kexts I have virtualbox (no machines started though), sophos anti-virus, cisco vpn client, and fuse. But none of the exts seems to be eating much RAM. In fact, the most hungry one seems to be the network card driver:

```
sh-3.2# kextstat -a | perl -e 'print sort { $reg = qr/^\s*(?:\S+\s+){3}0x([0-9a-f]+)\s+/; $a =~ $reg; $alen = $1; $b =~ $reg; $blen = $1; return hex($alen)<=>hex($blen) } (<>);' | tail -5
   63    5 0xffffff7f819cd000 0xe6000    0xe6000    x86_64             com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily (6.0.2) 949583EE-C099-3FB8-89A4-E04F8C5C2612 <5 4 3 1>
  139    1 0xffffff7f8324c000 0x131000   0x131000   x86_64             com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib (274.12) DF000E7A-97E3-3615-A721-BF31BAC181E8 <138 103 102 38 6 5 4 3 1>
  136    0 0xffffff7f813c0000 0x1af000   0x1af000   x86_64             com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal (10.1.0) EB8A5980-AB59-368A-8244-60A00C7A933C <131 12 4 3>
  131    2 0xffffff7f8113b000 0x27a000   0x27a000   x86_64             com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman (10.1.0) 8649777A-3EED-3F2F-8B12-FBC5517F62E6 <125 109 105 12 5 4 3 1>
   55    0 0xffffff7f81fc3000 0x6c2000   0x6c2000   x86_64             com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360 (1040.1.1a6) 24E8C306-1A42-3C1E-92EA-26D593D6D901 <54 53 52 51 12 7 6 5 4 3 1>
```

Here is the output from some memory-related utilities:

```
sh-3.2# memory_pressure
The system has 2147483648 (524288 pages with a page size of 4096).

Stats: 
Pages free: 616801 
Pages purgeable: 15526 
Pages purged: 3259312 

Swap I/O:
Swapins: 6405588 
Swapouts: 10159033 

Page Q counts:
Pages active: 1456513 
Pages inactive: 788877 
Pages speculative: 130285 
Pages throttled: 0 
Pages wired down: 1047560 

Compressor Stats:
Pages used by compressor: 152268 
Pages decompressed: 10186824 
Pages compressed: 22538934 

File I/O:
Pageins: 43075180 
Pageouts: 866697 

System-wide memory free percentage: 71%

sh-3.2# vm_stat
Mach Virtual Memory Statistics: (page size of 4096 bytes)
Pages free:                              617559.
Pages active:                           1452800.
Pages inactive:                          788952.
Pages speculative:                       130436.
Pages throttled:                              0.
Pages wired down:                       1049437.
Pages purgeable:                          15548.
"Translation faults":                3038318813.
Pages copy-on-write:                   30152835.
Pages zero filled:                   2672671870.
Pages reactivated:                     21893412.
Pages purged:                           3259312.
File-backed pages:                       760676.
Anonymous pages:                        1611512.
Pages stored in compressor:             1017392.
Pages occupied by compressor:            152268.
Decompressions:                        10186831.
Compressions:                          22538934.
Pageins:                               43075180.
Pageouts:                                866697.
Swapins:                                6405588.
Swapouts:                              10159033.
```

What to do next? Please don't send hints such as "reboot" or "force quit non-responding apps". Thank you!

Comment: Judging by the output from `memory_pressure`, I don't think it has to do with memory. The line `System-wide memory free percentage: 71%` suggests that there is sufficient memory to go around. Do you have anything that could be disk IO-intensive running? It seems like a case of disk IO saturation. Do look under Activity Monitor's Disk tab.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry no disk IO is not an issue. The notebook runs fine now (I'm writing this post on it), but the apps that I haven't killed are still stuck, and not a single bit of their memory have been uncompressed since my posting.